# Trouble with else if statements in C combined with a calculation

Tags: c, if-statement

Alright guys, I'm having a hell of a time with this. Currently I am working on if else statements in my C class (intro to programming, obviously) and I cannot seem to get the syntax for the if else statements correct. I've browsed the web and haven't found any relevant answers. The error I am currently receiving is:
|47|error: expected ')' before numeric constant|

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


float p(float r, float v)
{
  return (v*v)/(r);

    }

int main()
{


  float r, v, answer;                  //The user input and print for title of values
  puts("Enter Voltage:");
  scanf("%f", &r);
  puts("Enter Resistance:");
  scanf("%f", &v);
  answer = p(v, r);
   printf("Pd=%.9f\n", answer);

  return 0;


scanf("%f", answer);
if (answer >= 0.25)
{


       /* if condition is true then print the following */
       printf("WARNING: Power Dissipation should not exceed 1/4 Watt\n" );
}




else if ((answer) 0.25 < =<0.5 > )
      {

       printf("WARNING: Power Dissipation should not exceed 1/2 Watt\n" );

}

scanf("%f", &answer);
if ((answer 0.5<  & 1 >=< 1 )
       printf("WARNING: Power Dissipation should not exceed 1 Watt" );



}
```

If you've got a moment to spare, please help.

Comment: It would help to indent the code.

Comment: Your second and third `if` have a Bad Syntax. Review your course notes, please. (On re-reading: I cannot even fathom what you are trying to test...)

Comment: It looks like you have a `return` in the middle of your main.  That's probably not right.

Comment: `(answer) 0.25 < =<0.5 >` is not a valid C expression. Did you mean  `answer > 0.25 && answer <= 0.5` ?

Comment: That's the problem, I don't know the syntax. I am trying to give a statement warning the user about Wattage when calculations of (v*v)/(r) are completed by whether the answer is within certain ranges.

Comment: There is a wealth of resources available online that will help you learn proper C syntax.

Comment: @JamesZ Try describing in words what you are trying to achieve in your if statements, where you test the value of `answer`.

Comment: A good quick tutorial on `if` statements in C: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson2.html

Comment: @KLibby I am trying to have a message appear to the user that states that the wattage of the resistor cannot exceed a certain level, which assumes that the user knows what the resistor is, as when the users wattage calculation exceeds the value advised, it will be within a new range. It sounds stupid to me, but it's the assignment given.

Comment: I meant the range tests, for example `(answer) 0.25 < =<0.5 >`. Translate this into words and then use the tutorial above or the link in aruisdante's answer below, to convert it to C syntax.

Comment: I'll bet that you didn't find gibberish like "(answer) 0.25 < =<0.5 >" and "(answer 0.5<  & 1 >=< 1" on the web.

Comment: "I don't know the syntax" -- So you just through in random strings of characters? Maybe if you jumble them long enough they might look like `answer >= 0.25 && answer <= .5`.

Comment: "It sounds stupid to me" -- That might be because you've jumbled the words. There's nothing stupid about printing messages that indicate that a value is not within range ... it's very common.

Answer (score 2):

You have many syntactical errors:

```
((answer) 0.25 < =<0.5 >)
```

Is not valid C. This is likely where your error message is coming from. But later on, you also have

```
((answer 0.5<  & 1 >=< 1 )
```

This is also not valid C, and the `&` is *not* the `AND` operator, `&&` is. These have nothing to do with the `if` syntax, they're invalid expressions anywhere you'd find them.

It would likely help if you spelled out exactly what you were trying to accomplish with these statements. But, in general, you should probably re-review your basic C [boolean expression syntax](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx3c.html) before you start worrying about `if` statements.

Once you've done that, the general form of a an `if` statement in C is:

```
if(int){statements;}
```

Where `int` is considered to be `false` if it is `0`, and `true` if it is anything else (C lacks a native boolean type). Any expression you place inside the `()` must evaluate into an integer or be implicitly convertible to one. The statements between the `{}` are evaluated only if the expression was `true`.

Answer (score 1):

This condition is fairly straightforward:

```
if (answer >= 0.25)
```

These two, however...

```
else if ((answer) 0.25 < =<0.5 > )
if ((answer 0.5<  & 1 >=< 1 )
```

What, exactly, are you trying to test in these cases?

I'm going to assume (based on the print statements that follow) that you're checking to see if the power exceeds half a watt or a full watt, in which case they'd be similar to the first case:

```
if ( answer >= 0.5 ) 
if ( answer >= 1.0 )
```

sp your code would be structured as

```
if ( answer >= 0.25 )
  printf( "Warning: power dissipation should not exceed 1/4 watt\n" );
else if ( answer >= 0.5 )
  printf( "Warning: power dissipation should not exceed 1/2 watt\n" );
else if ( answer >= 1.0 )
  printf( "Warning: power dissipation should not exceed 1 watt\n" );
```

Except...

If `answer` is greater than or equal to 1.0, then it's also greater than or equal to 0.5 and 0.25;  the first branch will be taken, printing out the warning for exceeding a quarter watt, when you would probably want the warning for exceeding 1 watt to be printed.  You probably want to reverse the order of the tests, like so:

```
if ( answer >= 1.0 )
  printf( "Warning: power dissipation should not exceed 1 watt\n" );
else if ( answer >= 0.5 )
  printf( "Warning: power dissipation should not exceed 1/2 watt\n" );
else if ( answer >= 0.25 )
  printf( "Warning: power dissipation should not exceed 1/4 watt\n" );
else
  printf( "power dissipation does not exceed 1/4 watt\n" );
```

So, if `answer` is something like `0.75`, you'll get the warning for exceeding a half watt; if it's 0.35, you'll get the warning for exceeding a quarter watt, etc.